# Is there any way to downgrade or revert an update to the kernel?

Tags: kernel, 13.04

Today I installed the linux 3.9 Kernel update (because I heard it would fix sound through HDMI which I no longer have since installing 13.04). After restarted my computer and logging in my screen has only a desktop, and no dock or tool bar.

I tried to reset unity and compiz using guides like [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html) but nothing happens, even after reboot.

Is there any way to downgrade or reset the update?

EDIT:
Running `uname -a` in terminal brings up 3.8.0 as my current kernel for some reason.

Comment: @JorgeCastro He's asking how he can downgrade so his computer works again. How is this "off-topic"? He's not reporting a bug, he's asking for help so his PC isn't left unusable. Hard for him to file a bug report if his PC can't let him open a web browser.

Comment: Can you try booting off of the older kernel? http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old kernel should still be installed unless you manually removed it. On the Grub screen there should be an option to view old kernels and boot using them. If you're able to successfully boot using an old kernel you can then file a bug report and work on figuring out what went wrong. Or you can uninstall the new one and then run:

```
update-grub
```

To make Grub rescan the available kernels. That should return everything to before the kernel update, if not comment and I'll update with something more drastic.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out removing the update then updating grub and reseting unity/compiz did the trick!